# Invalid Object Name Exception Thrown on Update

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3, simplerepository, subsonic-simplerepository

I have a project using Simple Repository which was working before I rebuilt my dev machine. This may just be coincidence but I am now using SQL Server 2008 Express to develop against rather than 2005 and now when I run my project I get the exception "Invalid object name 'TableName'". the table exists as records are inserted fine but when it comes to update a record that is when the exception is thrown.

In case it helps this is an example of the code where the error is thrown:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the specified entity.   
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">The entity.</param>
    public void Update(IList<Result> entity)
    {
        using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
        {
            using (SharedDbConnectionScope scs = new SharedDbConnectionScope())
            {
                foreach (Result result in entity)
                {
                    Update(result);
                }

                ts.Complete();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Update(Result entity)
    {
        repo.Update(entity);
    }
```

Comment: I think this has to do with the SharedDbConnectionScope possibly using the wrong DB connection as removing it and the TransactionScope makes the error go away!?

Comment: This is a fairly common SQL error, often caused by security/access errors or by using the wrong schema. You really need to see the actual SQL, either by debugging or logging. Also check rights: can you DELETE? Or maybe it's generating the wrong SQL.